# Folder storage size from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, windows, sql-server-2014

There are dm views to find the disk sizes in SQL Server. How to find folder size on a drive?

One way is using a Windows command from `XP_CMDSHELL`. Is there any other way to achieve the same in SQL Server?

Comment: You could write custom CLR function. Something like [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2582/introduction-to-sql-server-clr-table-valued-functions/)

Comment: Just curious, what are you using it for that you need to access that info from SQL?